# Parse Soap XML Response

Tags: php, xml, parsing, soap, response

I need to parse the following XML response:

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP:Body><m:LoginResponse xmlns:m="http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/" UserGUID="{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}" UserID="1" LoginGUID=""/></SOAP:Body></SOAP:Envelope>
```

I need to get the UserGUID, so I created the following peace of code:

```
$xmlResponse = $client->__doRequest($xml_request, $this->__url_request, "XML", SOAP_1_1);

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlResponse);

        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('m', 'http://www.e-courier.com/schemas/');


        foreach ($xml->xpath('//LoginResponse') as $a)
        {
            error_log(print_r($a));
        }
```

The problem is that I never get anything printed on the error_log.
What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I found out that $xml is not being created successfully... Should I use something before calling simplexml_load_string?

Comment: You register a namespace without using it (`//m:LoginResponse`). Any reason not to use the built-in SoapClient which does all the heavy lifting for you BTW?

Comment: I didn't know I could use soapclient... any documentation?

Comment: Well, there's a lot in the [manual for SOAP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) & the [`SoapClient`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)